# How to define a (color) variable depending on a criteria?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

For example, IF something is bigger than something else then I want to redefine a color variable. If trying, I get the following error:

```
'IF' is not a valid type keyword in variable declaration
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [usrman page on Colors](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Colors.html#conditional-coloring) where you will find this example, among many others:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Conditional colors", "", true)
int   lengthInput = input.int(20, "Length", minval = 2)
color maBullColorInput = input.color(color.green, "Bull")
color maBearColorInput = input.color(color.maroon, "Bear")
float ma = ta.sma(close, lengthInput)
// Define our states.
bool maRising  = ta.rising(ma, 1)
// Build our color.
color c_ma = maRising ? maBullColorInput : maBearColorInput
plot(ma, "MA", c_ma, 2)
```